# HttpClient returns data with default values (Blazor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, webassembly

I have the Blazor WASM application (dotnet 6). I can't get the data from the api controller. The call hits the controller method. HttpClient receives a response, the status is OK, but the returned data has default values. Can you please advise me what I'm doing wrong?

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

```c#
// Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("data")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestStruc), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
    {
        var data = new TestStruc();
        data.Id = 7;
        data.IsUse = true;
        data.Path = "root/bin/item";

        await Task.Delay(10); // instead of async query on db

        return HttpApiRep.Ok(data);
    }
}
```

```c#
// Blazor:
var res = await Http.GetAsync("test/data");
// res.StatusCode - Status code is OK
var data = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TestStruc>();
// data have default values
```

```c#
// Data structure
public class TestStruc
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public bool IsUse { get; set; } = false;
    public string Path { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Update:

If I call `await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, I'll get:

```
{"data":{"id":7,"isUse":true,"path":"root/bin/item"},"status":"ok","errorCode":"undefined","errorMessage":"","isOk":true}
```

But when I call `await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TestStruc> ()`, I get an object with default values.

Maybe a problem with deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `HttpApiRep` ?  I think it wraps your return.

This should work:

```
//return HttpApiRep.Ok(data);
  return Ok(data);
```

or, make sure `HttpApiRep` or a simulacrum is available in the Client and use

```
var response = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<HttpApiRep>();
var data = response.data;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was incredibly blind. I read it many times and I didn't see it. You correctly pointed out ```HttpApiRep```. Which is a custom object to wrap the answer. When I moved the code from dotnet 5 to dotnet 6, I forgot to delete it here. Thank you. And I'm deleting this post.